# How to get Nth value from a list in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a basic question about Power BI but I cannot find the answer anywhere and I don't have the time to take an entire course in DAX before I can do something so basic.

I have a column containing a list of values which are latitude and longitude, and I'm trying to define a measure for each.

In essence I just want to do something like LatitudeMeasure = Locations[0], LongitudeMeasure = Locations[1]. But it doesn't seem to be that simple.

I have no idea how to do it, I'm finding nothing online and I don't feel like completely redesigning my table structure just for something so basic.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected output from them?

Comment: Don't use DAX, best practice would be to separate the list into two new columns in the power query import https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/M-language-help-get-an-element-from-a-list-by-index/td-p/565023